# getting data from xml into html using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i am getting data from XML into html using jquery, i build a function which is working perfectly which is given below

```
function parseXml(xml){
    xmlcontent = xml;
    $('#file').html('$'+ GetDeals('delhi','india'));
    $('#file1').html('$'+ GetDeals('mumbai','india'));
    $('#file2').html('$'+ GetDeals('kolkata','india'));    
}

function GetDeals(state, country){
    var lowestPrice=0;    
    $(xmlcontent).find("ndata[nstate='"+state+"'][ncountry='"+ country +"']").each(function(){
        lowestPrice =  parseInt($(this).attr('price')) ;
    });
    return lowestPrice;    
}
```

now i want pick pick one more field call cityrating from xml for example first parameter contains cityrating= 1, and second cityrating=2, and last one is 3 and i wana get it in new div, i struggle with it almost 3 hour but it is not working my change function given below. when i am running this function cityrating replace by last cityrating for example all parameter cityrating replaced by 3

```
function parseXml(xml){
    xmlcontent = xml;
    $('#file').html('$'+ GetDeals('delhi','india'));
    $('#file1').html('$'+ GetDeals('mumbai','india'));
    $('#file2').html('$'+ GetDeals('kolkata','india'));    
}

function GetDeals(state, country){
    var lowestPrice=0;
    var cityRating=[];

    $(xmlcontent).find("ndata[nstate='"+state+"'][ncountry='"+ country +"']").each(function(){
        lowestPrice =  parseInt($(this).attr('price'));
        cityRating.push(parseInt($(this).attr('CityRating')));
        $('.city').html(cityRating[0])
    });
    return lowestPrice;    
}
```

//my html

```
<div id="file"></div>
<div class="city"></div>

<div id="file1"></div>
<div class="city"></div>

<div id="file2"></div>
<div class="city"></div>
```

Comment: when i alert(cityRating) it is showing correct value in alert box but it is showing one by one like first time 1 then 2 and 3 .push method not joining them together

Comment: method to call xml is $(function() {
 $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: "newdata.xml",  
 
    dataType: "xml",  
    success: parseXml 
  });
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are trying to find an element with class `city` which does not exist.

It should be `$('#city').html(cityRating[0])` instead `$('.city').html(cityRating[0])`

Comment: @amit can you provide your sample xml. I can use it in jsfiddle

Comment: <ndata nstate="delhi" ncountry="india" price="200" cityRating="1"  />

<ndata nstate="mumbai" ncountry="india" price="300" cityRating="2"  />

<ndata nstate="kolkata" ncountry="india" price="400" cityRating="3"  />

Comment: I see one more typo. It should be `parseInt($(this).attr('cityRating'))` instead `parseInt($(this).attr('CityRating'))`

Comment: @amit Also im not sure what result you want. Because when you do `$('.city').html(cityRating[0])`, rating will be changed for all the matched `div`s with class `city`. If you want corresponding city rating to be displayed, you need to send corresponding `div` ids to `GetDeals` function

Comment: i want that i have three div which have class city in first city div i want rating 1, in second city div i want rating 2 and in last city div i want cityrating 3, but when i am running this function all the city div appending with cityrating= 3

Comment: you can see you in XML every parameter cityrating is different but in you given example all city div replaced by cityrating 3 that what i am trying to say

Comment: @amit I have updated the jsfiddle link. Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U99JD/1/).

Comment: OMG! it is working thank a lot sir for your such a nice effort many many thank sir